# Matlab 2018a: can't upload keras .h5 model using Deep Learning Toolbox

Tags: matlab, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, toolbox

I have a .h5 file I want to upload to Matlab using the import tool for TensorFlow in matlab, like this:

```
layers = importKerasLayers('myModel.h5');
```

But I get the following error:

> Option to import Keras networks containing LSTM layers is not yet
> supported.
>
> layers =importKerasLayers('myModel.h5');

I've tried this in 2018a, and apperantly all layers related to LSTM are available in this version after the toolbox is downloaded, but I keep getting the error. [In this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importkeraslayers.html), you can see the toolbox has support for LSTM layers, but not sure what's causing the error then.

Is there any workaround to solve this? What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your link is for R2018b documentation. This is the [R2018a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/nnet/ref/importkeraslayers.html) documentation and it shows no support for LSTM! So probably switch versions and try!

Comment: A friend of mine has 2018b and didn't work either. 

Also, the LSTM layers discussed in the compatibility table in the link I gave discuss these 2:

1) https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.lstmlayer.html

2) https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.bilstmlayer.html

1st one says on the bottom of the page "introduced in R2017b" and the 2nd one says "introduced in R2018a", so I don't think this is the issue. Still, I'll try this out.

Comment: Ohh. I'm not sure if there is correspondence between when it was introduced to whether it is supported by this importKerasLayers method and I suspect it may not be the case. This is because importKerasLayers method of R2018a does not seem to support lstm from that documentation.

Comment: I'll try this out in the upcoming days and if it works, I'll report back here. Thanks anyways @kvish! :)

Comment: Sure! Hope it works out. Not very familiar with how things work in matlab!